# Что означает знак ^ в js?

Tags: javascript

`const stray = nums => nums.reduce((a, b) => a ^ b);`

Comment: побитовое исключающее или

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/bitwise-operators

Comment: Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 2):

Bitwise XOR - побитовое исключающее ИЛИ.
[На MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR) можно посмотреть демо.